# Style Dynamically Generated Divs

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am attempting to style divs that are echo'd to the front page.
[image]

I am working in WordPress, so when a user creates a new post, I would like the first post to stick to the left, then the next to the right, etc.

I attempted this like so:

```
            echo '<div class="popImage">';
            the_post_thumbnail();
            echo '</div>';
```

and then targeting it using :nth-child(odd) and :nth-child(even). However upon creating the third post, in the front end the box would appear beside the 1st post.

I'm wondering if there is any way to do this, or if my whole approach is fundamentally incorrect. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Below is the failed CSS:

```
.popImage {
width: 15rem;
height: 15rem;
background-color: #3700ff;
display: inline-block;

}

.popImage:nth-child(even) {
float: left;
}

.popImage:nth-child(odd) {
float: right;
background-color: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't quite understand your issue, but, it seems that you want to make a 2 columns grid in each column you put the new post alongside to the last post.
Here is a representation of what the sniippet that i'll give would look like:

~~~~~

| [p] [p] |

| [p] [p] |

| [p] [p] |

~~~~~

I hope you understand what I meant.
So, here's a snippet to accomplish this grid (i'll be using `float` here as your attempt, but, I strongly suggest you use `flexbox` instead):

```
.popImage {
    margin: 1rem 0;
    width: 49%;
    height: 15rem;
    background-color: #3700ff;
    display: block; /* must be block in order to work correctly */
    float: left;
}
.popImage:nth-child(even) {
    margin-left: 1%;
}
.popImage:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: yellow;
    margin-right: 1%;
}
.popImage img {
    height: 100%; 
    width: 100%;
}
```

**Ps:** I recommand using a container for the posts that wraps all the `.popImage` `div`s and then use its `::after` pseudo-element to clear the float, for example:

```
.popImageWrapper:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
    /* writing only one colon before the word after instead of two colons(::) to support older browsers */
}
```

Hope I pushed you further.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the `float` properties I believe you will get the effect you desire. If you wish to preserve the offset spacing, you could add a `position:relative;` to `.popImage` and use `top` or `bottom` to set the offset value.

Ah, and to address the left/right balance, you could restrict the `.popImage` container to only accommodate two images.

If it were me, I'd probably use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) :)